Programmatic access to Google sheet tables via Apps script API?
Having discovered Apps script for Google sheet, I successfully automated the creation of multiple copies of a source sheet within a single spreadsheet. Perfect.
However, the source sheet in question contains a "table" which seems to be a recent addition to Google sheet features. When the sheet is copied using
SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo()

the table it contains gets copied too (great), but renamed from "TableName" to "TableName_x" where "x" reflects the number of copies so far.
I would like to rename the new table programmatically, but haven't been able to locate any part of the API allowing me to do so.Is it possible, and if yes, what are the Service/API classes I should be using ?
Thanks :)

About I would like to rename the new table programmatically, in the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that there are no built-in methods for managing the table name in Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and Sheets API. But, I guess that this might be able to be achieved by the future update. So, as the current action, how about reporting it to the Google issue tracker as a future request? Ref

Thanks a lot @Tanaike, good suggestion. I will create the issue (or find one which covers it already if any), and will post the link here.

Feature request raised with Google here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/364038444
